# Parse: undeclared type 'PFFile' (POD 1.17.2)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, pffile

In an iOS app using the Parse pod.

```
pod 'Parse'
```

After I update the pod from version 1.17.1 to version 1.17.2, using this command line:

```
$ pod update
```

I get these two error messages when compiling the app:

On this line of code:

```
parse_Sound = PFFile(name: "Voice", data: soundData)
```

This error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'PFFile'; did you mean 'PFRole'?

On this line of code:

```
if let audioFile = item.value(forKey: "audio") as? PFFile {...}
```

This error:

> Use of undeclared type 'PFFile'

I did not have these issues before doing the update.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: have you import Parse file in your controller ?

Comment: This was done long before I had this problem and it has not changed. So to answer your question: YES "import Parse" is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PFFile` is renamed to `PFFileObject`. Just change your code to the below:

```
parse_Sound = PFFileObject(name: "Voice", data: soundData)
```

And

```
if let audioFile = item.value(forKey: "audio") as? PFFileObject {...}
```